# Is it correct to use a return statement within a try and except statement?

Tags: python, methods, exception, return, try-except

If I have such code in the end of function:

```
try:
    return map(float, result)
except ValueError, e:
    print "error", e
```

Is it correct to use try / except in return part of method?
Is there a wiser way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, you can use `try` around a `return`. There is not enough context here to suggest a 'better' way.

Comment: Just be aware that your method will return `None` as it is. A broader context will allow for smarter suggetions

Comment: In plain English, what do you want to happen in this function if `map()` results in an error?  Aside from printing the error.  Do you want the function to return `None`? To return another value? To allow the exception to propagate up the call stack after printing the error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Keep it simple: no try block

It took me a while to learn, that in Python it is natural, that functions throw exceptions up. I have spent too much effort on handling these problems in the place the problem occurred.

The code can become much simpler and also easier to maintain if you simply let the exception bubble up. This allows for detecting problems on the level, where it is appropriate.

One option is:

```
try:
    return map(float, result)
except ValueError, e:
    print "error", e
    raise
```

but this introduces print from within some deep function. The same can be provided by `raise` which let upper level code to do what is appropriate.

With this context, **my preferred solution looks**:

```
return map(float, result)
```

No need to dance around, do, what is expected to be done, and throw an exception up, if there is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you surround the code block containing a `return` statement with an `try`/`except` clause, you should definitely spend some thoughts of what should be returned, if an exception actually occurs:

In you example, the function will simply return `None`. If it's that what you want, I would suggest to explicitely add a `return None` like

```
except ValueError, e:
    print "error", e
    return None
```

in your `except` block to make that fact clear.

Other possibilities would be to return a "default value" (empty map in this case) or to "reraise" the exception using

```
except ValueError, e:
    print "error", e
    raise
```

It depends on how the function is used, under what circumstances you expect exceptions and on your general design which option you want to choose.

Comment: If the result of mapping is good there should be f.e. [22.99, 44.34] in result , but if its wrong it will be good to raise some exception, but not to stop execution of the program

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case in languages with exceptions, programmers assume that printing an error message "handles" it.

Printing an error message doesn't handle anything; you might as well have put `pass` there instead. This causes problems because the the code was expecting the `try` block to accomplish something and that something has not happened.

In Python, you should:

1. figure out where the error can actually be handled in the sense that the fault is actually rectified, or
2. let the exception unwind to the top and abort the program

Having a program abort with an exception is infinitely better than having it run and yield inaccurate results.

So unless you know that your code can accept an empty list, you shouldn't return anything that you thought deserved a try block.